# How to find unique couples of numbers in a vector in R?

Tags: r

Let us suppose to have `C<-c(1,2,3,4,5)`
I want to find all the unique couples of numbers that can be extracted from this vector, e.g.,12,13 23 etc. How can I do it?

Comment: Try: `combn(c(1,2,3,4,5), 2)`

Comment: or `expand.grid(C, C)` ?

Comment: It works and is satisfactory. The first option is better and I can manage it easier than expand.grid that returns in the different columns combinations like 11 etc.

Comment: You can also pass a function to it so as to paste the values together `combn(1:5, 2, paste0, collapse = '')`

Comment: @RonakShah  I was about to post the same but `paste` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Using `RcppAlgos` package.

```
## Combinations
unlist(RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(x, 2, FUN=function(x) Reduce(paste0, x)))
# [1] "12" "13" "14" "15" "23" "24" "25" "34" "35" "45"

## Permutations
unlist(RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(x, 2, FUN=function(x) Reduce(paste0, x)))
# [1] "12" "13" "14" "15" "21" "23" "24" "25" "31" "32" "34" "35" "41" "42" "43"
# [16] "45" "51" "52" "53" "54"
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
na.omit(c(`diag<-`(sapply(x, paste0, x), NA)))

 [1] "12" "13" "14" "15" "21" "23" "24" "25" "31" "32" "34" "35" "41" "42" "43" "45"
[17] "51" "52" "53" "54"
```

Comment: I will also post an answer in full given that I found the strategy I was searching for!